# Null value not getting picked in coalesce sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a query to fetch values from mapping staging table for location and job code

```
 SELECT ORG_NAME,
        COALESCE(JOB_MAP.FUSION_HARMONIZED_CODE,JOB_CODE) JOB_CODE,
        JOB_SET_CODE,
        COALESCE(LOC_MAP.FUSION_HARMONIZED_CODE,LOCATION_CODE)LOCATION_CODE 
      FROM XX_POS POS_STAG,
        XX_MAP JOB_MAP,
        XX_MAP LOC_MAP
      WHERE JOB_MAP.SOURCE_CORE_HR_CODE(+)= POS_STAG.JOB_CODE
      AND JOB_MAP.TABLE_CODE(+)           ='JOB'
      AND POS_STAG.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME     =JOB_MAP.business_unit
      AND LOC_MAP.TABLE_CODE(+)           ='LOC'
      AND LOC_MAP.SOURCE_CORE_HR_CODE(+)  = POS_STAG.LOCATION_CODE
      AND POS_STAG.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME     =LOC_MAP.BUSINESS_UNIT;
```

But this query is not picking up value for location_code which is null in xx_pos table. Do i have to change my where condition ?

Comment: Still someone use this `(+)` syntax in `JOIN's` :x

Comment: I suspect that rewriting your query using explicit `left join` syntax will fix the problems.

Comment: @MotoGP- Oh! I am more comfortable using (+) will change it soon.

Comment: @GordonLinoff- Ok i am not used to doing that. Will re-write and check

Comment: @divya.trehan573 - Sample data and expected result will help us to understand better

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the query you want:

```
 SELECT ORG_NAME,
        COALESCE(JOB_MAP.FUSION_HARMONIZED_CODE, JOB_CODE) as JOB_CODE,
        JOB_SET_CODE,
        COALESCE(LOC_MAP.FUSION_HARMONIZED_CODE, LOCATION_CODE) as LOCATION_CODE 
FROM XX_POS POS_STAG LEFT JOIN
     XX_MAP JOB_MAP
     ON JOB_MAP.SOURCE_CORE_HR_CODE = POS_STAG.JOB_CODE AND
         JOB_MAP.TABLE_CODE = 'JOB' LEFT JOIN
     XX_MAP LOC_MAP
     ON LOC_MAP.SOURCE_CORE_HR_CODE = POS_STAG.LOCATION_CODE AND
        LOC_MAP.BUSINESS_UNIT = POS_STAG.BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME AND
        LOC_MAP.TABLE_CODE = 'LOC';
```

Comment: I am getting 4029 rows with my query by using (+) but with the above query I am getting 30000

Comment: @divya.trehan573 . . . Because two of your join conditions are converting the outer join to an inner join.  When you mix inner an out joins, it is a bit hard to tell what the intended results should be.